# Passing item data to Yii2 sortable widget

Tags: widget, jquery-ui-sortable, yii2

I'm using the Yii2 sortable widget to produce drag and drop lists but I can't figure out how to add item data to each `<li>` element.  I would like to be able to use something similar to a gridview like this :-

```
echo Sortable::widget([
    'items' =>  ArrayHelper::map(Product::find()->all(), 'id', 'FullDescription'),
    'options' => ['tag' => 'ul', 'class'=>'connectedSortable', 'style'=>"min-height: 20px; border: 1px solid #000;"],
    'itemOptions' => ['tag' => 'li', 'data'=>['id'=>'$item->id']], // <-- this doesn't evaluate
    'clientOptions' => [  
       ...
    ],
]);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in doc, you should simply put this data in items, e.g. :

```
$items = [];
$products = Product::find()->all();
foreach ($products as $p) {
    $items[$p->id] = [
        'content' => p->FullDescription,
        'options' => ['data' => ['id'=>$p->id]],
    ];
}

echo Sortable::widget([
    ...
    'items' => $items,
    ...
]);
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-jui-sortable.html#$items-detail